# AOS on scroll animation loading prior to showing in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've added the [AOS on scroll](http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) javascript to my website. I know that the script is working properly but for some reason the animation that I've added to the logo with the purple background (below the yoga photo) is animating before it's visible in the viewport. I assume this might have something to do with the fact that the height of the top portion of the page is created dynamically based on the viewport, but I'm not totally sure what the issue is.

Here's a link to the website: http://awaken1.thecustompixel.com/

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page you can see the script is working properly with the three-column section. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see that you removed AOS animation from this logo, if you could add it once again I could check why it's not working. But I think that setting `data-aos-offset="0"` on this element might resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured out the problem. I was adding the AOS tags to the SVG element originally. I wrapped the SVG in a div and added the AOS tag to the div instead of the svg and it started working.